# How to specify number of rows to insert to another table with psycopg2?

Tags: python, insert, psycopg2, execute

I want to copy around 500k of records from one table to another. To specify I want to copy only one column from row.

Surely I don't want to do it in one big insert statement so I was wondering how to do it with batch inserts, the thing is I'm not sure if I get it right how batch_insert works here. What I want to achieve is to do this insert in parts of a 1000 rows into another table.

Here's my approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras
from config import config

def connect():
    conn = None
    try:
        params = config()
        conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
        cur = conn.cursor()
    
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            cur.execute("select id from old_table where id like '%test%'")
            results = cur.fetchall()
    
    sql = "insert into new_table select id from old_table where id like '%test%'"

    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        data_gen =  ((rIdx, cIdx, value) for rIdx, cData in enumerate(results) for cIdx, value in enumerate(cData))
        psycopg2.extras.execute_batch(cur, sql, data_gen, page_size=1000*len(results[0]))
        conn.commit()
   
except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
    print(error)
finally:
    if conn is not None:
        conn.close()
```

Could someone please tell me if I get it right that this will insert in batch 1000 rows until the end of list of selected products?

EDIT:
I can see that after execute_batch to my new table instead of inserting specified amount of records I have inserted much more with duplicates. Why? :( I tried this on smaller example to insert 248 records but in the new table there are 1,783,616 new records instead of 248 which is totally not understandable for me. What am I doing wrong?
I've calculated that 1,783,616 is 248 * 248 * size_of_record (29).

Thanks for any help.